# How to save MS Word template file (dotx) as docx when document is opened in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, templates, ms-word

I am maintaining a web application that allows word template documents do be opened inside the browser.

Recently the client upgraded to windows 7 and MS Word 2007 and my problems started... When a template document is opened inside the browser and saved, the original file is overwrited instead of a new word file being created.

Is there a way to force ms word inside the browser to behave the same as when it runs outside  the browser?

Answer (score 0):

See [Knowledgebase Article 278627 from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/278627/word-template-hyperlink-is-opened-instead-of-new-document) ("Word template hyperlink is opened instead of new document"). It references Office 2003, but I believe it applies to Office 2007 as well...

The workaround involves creating a Hyperlink to a Windows link-file (*.lnk) instead of the actual template. Although you have to enter the path manualy, because the document-browser, which allows you to navigate to the correct (link-)file, will automatically resolve the link path back to the template path.